# Angular2, Error: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '0

Tags: angular, typescript, carousel

I have used `carousel` in that i have used `activeSlideIndex` to get the number of that particular image. So i get an error in console

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '0'.
```

HTML Part:

```
   <carousel class="carousel slide"[(activeSlide)]="page.activeSlideIndex">
                <slide *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index ">
                  <p>Image {{i+1}}</p>
                  <img src="{{image.image}}" >
                  <p >
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" (change)="readUrl($event)" />
                    <label (click)="changed(page.activeSlideIndex)">Change</label>
                  </p>
                </slide>
              </carousel>
```

ts:

```
images:any = [{image :'img1.jpg', change:'change'},{image: 'img2.jpg', change:'add'},{image:'img3.jpg', change:'edit'},{image:'im4.jpg',change:'delete' }];

    changed(index){
        console.log(index);
      }
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using ChangeDetectorRef to tell angular that there are new changes to the data sets of image.

so initially set

```
image.any = [];

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.image.any = [{image :'img1.jpg', change:'change'},{image: 'img2.jpg', change:'add'},{image:'img3.jpg', change:'edit'},{image:'im4.jpg',change:'delete' }];

    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

Check this for reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pybs8e?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the response @jana, but i am unable to solve that error

Comment: may be then the issue is not related to your images object. Try similar solution where you have your 'page.activeSlideIndex' defined. If still issue persists...reproduce in stackblitz and share the url..that way it is better to understand your issue clearly.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell the exact problem when not all your code is shown, but I suggest reading this amazing article which describes this error and why it is happening https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError is special check which is thrown only on dev mode if you view and model is possible out of sync for some reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i am not getting way to solve

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution which I found!!

First, detach change detector which will stop detecting any changes.

```
constructor( private cdRef : ChangeDetectorRef) {
   this.cdRef.detach();
}
```

Then, whenever you want to trigger changeDetector to paint the DOM, trigger manually.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataProvider.getProductData('someProduct').subscribe(res => {
      this.product = _.get(res, '0');
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  })
}
```

If you have any child components, which makes changes to DOM, then trigger ChangeDetector there as well.

This solved my problem and increased the performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `*ngIf="page.activeSlideIndex && images"` like this:

```js
<carousel *ngIf="page.activeSlideIndex && images" class="carousel slide" [(activeSlide)]="page.activeSlideIndex">
                <slide *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index ">
                  <p>Image {{i+1}}</p>
                  <img src="{{image.image}}" >
                  <p >
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" (change)="readUrl($event)" />
                    <label (click)="changed(page.activeSlideIndex)">Change</label>
                  </p>
                </slide>
              </carousel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i am getting same error after adding also

Comment: ok, your error is binded to `activateSlideIndex` right? sorry i didn't see it. Instead of *ngIf="images", try using `*ngIf="page.activeSlideIndex"`

Comment: yes, exactly. the issue is with that activateSlideIndex

Comment: if, i remove that activateSlideIndex, then i face one more error with ng-select for using [multiple]="true"

Comment: that is for the carousel `<slide>`, i don't know it well but i think is necessary the `activeSlideIndex` when using `*ngFor` inside slides

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161441/discussion-between-luca-taccagni-and-bhrungarajni).